# Most optimal way to programmatically check if site is running locally or on a server with Django?

Tags: python, database, django

Currently I have this in my `settings.py` file:

```
DEBUG = True
LOCAL = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

SITE_TITLE = 'Stack Overflow Question'

REMOTE_SITE_URL = "http://************:8080"
LOCAL_SITE_URL  = "http://************:8000"

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

if LOCAL:
    SITE_URL = LOCAL_SITE_URL
    ROOT_URL = '/mnt/hgfs/Sites/************'
    engine = 'sqlite3'
    dbName = '************.db'
    dbUser = ''
    dbPassword = ''
    dbHost = ''
    dbPort = ''
else:
    SITE_URL = REMOTE_SITE_URL
    ROOT_URL = '/var/www/vhosts/www.*************.com/public/'
    engine = 'mysql'
    dbName = '************'
    dbUser = 'www-data'
    dbPassword = '************'
    dbHost = ''
    dbPort = ''
```

The idea is that if I modify `LOCAL=True` to false, I can switch between the `sqlite3` database and the `mysql` that's kept on the server. But this is cumbersome when using SVN. What I want is the ability for `settings.py` to intelligently know if it's on the server or running locally. Is there a way to sniff the URL, IP or simply check a file that exists on the server and not locally? Not only am I looking for a solution, but one that doesn't tax the server. Checking if a file exists might be a bit heavy of a process if it occurs every time Django renders a page. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checking if a file exists will not occur every time a render occurs.  It will actually only occur whenever you interpreter process is started, which all depends on your deployment configuration.  This will depend on a variety on your webserver setup, but if you are using apache, chiefly MaxRequestPerChild and StartServers, and related parameters.  For example, if I have

```
StartServers 8
MaxrequestsPerChild 4000
```

in a preforked apache, I will test that file for the first 8 requests, listen to 32,000 more requests, then test that file 8 more times.  (Yes, I know it's *much* more complicated than this.)

The point is, most implementations that load your code will not re-source the settings.py file very often.  With that in mind, how about:

```
import os
if os.uname()[1] == 'my.development.server.com':
    LOCAL = True
else:
    LOCAL = False
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again for the quick response. I think this works out great.